# Attaching debugger to multiple processes

Tags: visual-studio, azure-service-fabric

Very simple question from new user of multiple processes debugging.

Whenever I read MSDN articles regarding this topic, I read:

"You can attach to multiple processes when you are debugging, but only one process is active in the debugger at any given time"

If you can debug only single process actively, seemingly attaching multiple processes is not very useful if I can only activate a single process in the debugger.

Please correct me if I am not understanding the statement correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that while debugging, VS studio will switch between processes being debugged to gather information needed for debugging, otherwise would be a mess to understand what is happening to a process if multiple processes information are shown together.

An example to see it happening is creating a solution with two web applications and start debugging, VS itself will run both and attach to then, if you put a breakpoint in one endpoint of each app and call one endpoint, let's say here on app1, VS will stop on that breakpoint, and then call the endpoint on app2 before continuing the debugging on app1, visual Studio Will only switch to the other breakpoint when the first one gets released, than VS Will switch to app2 breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks, so it seems both breakpoints in two apps will get eventually hit anyway.  As long as that can be done, It seems meets the purpose.